Differential Amplifier: Common-mode rejection
From Fundamentals of Microelectronics, Behzad Razavi
For this circuit:

The following equations are given:


From which it concludes

Now, let us vary VCM in Fig. 10.7 by a small amount and determine the circuit’s response.
Interestingly, Eqs. (10.13)–(10.15) remain unchanged, thereby suggesting that neither the
collector current nor the collector voltage of the transistors is affected. We say the circuit
does not respond to changes in the input common-mode level, or the circuit “rejects” input
CM variations.

How does changing the common-mode voltage V_CM not change V_BE, and in turn change I_C? Is the change in voltage "absorbed" by the ideal current source I_EE (KVL: V_CM = V_BE + V_I_EE)?

The bases are wired together. The emitters are wired together. Both bipolars have the exact same $V_{_\text{BE}}$. In the ideal active-mode case, assuming they aren't driven into saturation by the collector resistors and the emitter current sink shown, both collectors must have the same current and therefore equally split the emitter current sink's value. Moving the common mode voltage up and down only means altering the voltage across that ideal current source. The voltage drop across the collector resistors should not change.

How to reveal the basic idea
To simplify the common-mode configuration of the differential amplifier and better understand its core concept, we can make the following assumptions:

Due to the circuit's symmetry, analyzing only half of it is sufficient.
As the collector resistor does not influence the circuit's operation, we can omit it.

This simplified circuit is essentially an emitter follower with a constant current source (aka dynamic load) connected to its emitter. The current source is usually implemented with a common-emitter transistor stage; so it can be also considered as an interconnection of a common-collector and a common-emitter stage (aka cascode circuit).
Since an emitter follower itself acts as a voltage source, the entire circuit can be viewed as an interconnection of a voltage source and a current source. So, to understand it, we need to have a good understanding of the behavior of both types of sources.
Interacting sources
Possible connections
Some of the most interesting and enigmatic electronic circuits that mimic human behavior are based on the interaction between electrical sources. There are two types of sources, therefore four combinations are possible between them (parentheses show typical applications):
Helping dissimilar sources:

Current source helps voltage source (CC-CE cascode, differential-amplifier common mode)

Voltage source helps current source (CE-CC cascode, differential-amplifier bias mode)


Opposing similar sources:

Current source opposes current source (dynamic load)

Voltage source opposes voltage source (differential-amplifier differential mode)


Helping current source
Your circuit is based on the first configuration where a current source helps voltage source. Let's see what this aid is.
V = 10 V, I = 1 mA: Imagine that initially a 10 V voltage source V is loaded with a 1 mA current source I.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
V = 15 V, I = 1 mA: Now imagine that we increase the voltage by 5 V. The current source manages (by some means unknown to us at this point) to keep the current constant. Thus, the voltage source "sees" an infinite differential resistance Rd = dV/dI = (15 - 10)/ (1 - 1) -> ∞. Figuratively speaking, it has the feeling that nothing is connected as a load.

Helping dynamic resistor
Conceptual circuit: In an electronic circuit, there is only one true voltage source (power supply). The remaining sources are derivatives of it and are made through dynamic resistors (transistors).
So, your circuit can be represented by two variable resistors in series forming a voltage divider. The voltage "source" Rv changes its resistance so that to keep the voltage constant, and the current "source" Ri changes its resistance to keep the current constant.

simulate this circuit
Visualized circuit: To visualize the voltage and currents, voltmeters and ammeters should be connected. We can simplify the schematic by combining a meter and resistor into a "visualized resistor" (i.e., replacing the resistors with meters having the same internal resistance).
Rv = 10 kΩ, Ri = 10 kΩ: Imagine initially both resistors have an equal resistance of 10 kΩ. The total resistance is 20 kΩ, the current is V/(Ri + Rv) = 20/(10 + 10) = 1 mA, the voltage is Vout = V.Ri/(Ri + Rv) = 10.10/(10 + 10) = 5 V.

simulate this circuit
Rv = 5 kΩ, Rv = 15 kΩ: Now imagine that the voltage source wants to increase the voltage by 5 V. To do this, it starts to decrease its resistance Rv. At the same time, however, the current source tries to keep the current constant and therefore begins to increase its resistance Ri. Thus, the total resistance remains constant at 20 kΩ and the current at 1mA. In the end, the resistances are Rv = 5 kΩ, Ri = 15 kΩ, and the voltage is 15 V.

simulate this circuit
In this way, Ri "helps" Rv in its desire to increase the voltage with 5 V. We get something like a "differential voltage divider".
Transistor implementation
Rc = 0: In the transistor circuit, a transistor serves as Rv and a current source as Ri.

simulate this circuit

Is the change in voltage "absorbed" by the ideal current source...?

Exactly! As the input voltage Vcm increases linearly from 1 V to 10 V, the transistor gradually decreases its effective collector-emitter "resistance", while the current source simultaneously increases its "resistance". This dynamic adjustment maintains a constant 1 mA current, smoothly transitioning the voltage drop between the two components.

So, the transistor, aided by the current source, operates effortlessly without the need to adjust its base-emitter voltage.
Rc = 10 kΩ: Even with Rc resistor included in the collector...

simulate this circuit
... the result is the same.

Early effect
While the collector-emitter voltage varies, the current remains constant due to the current source's regulation.


How does changing the common-mode voltage V_CM not change V_BE

It does change Vbe, and each transistor's Vbe is "in series" with the input signal on its base, so Vbe is directly added to the input signal. This is why a difference in Vbe due to mismatch will manifest as an input offset voltage.
However, if the two transistors are well matched, then Vbe change is the same for both, so it cancels out.
The constant current source (Iee in your schematic) ensures the sum of Ie in both transistors is constant. The differential input voltage (between the two transistor bases) determines what share of Iee each transistor takes.
If you write down the equations, you'll notice as long as both Vbe's are the same, the actual value doesn't matter.
In theory, this circuit has perfect common mode rejection. With real transistors, it depends how well they match. With modern ICs, they match pretty well. With random discretes picked from the same lot, they kinda match, but results will be a lot less reliable. Of course, Vbe depends on current and temperature too, so if both transistors run at different currents and temperatures, then common mode rejection will degrade, along with other parameters like offset. This is why this circuit works best as the input stage of an amplifier with a lot of open loop gain, so it only has to handle tiny signals, ie the difference in current between both transistors is very small.
The circuit in the question uses resistors as collector load. If the differential output current is tiny compared to the bias current, then we can consider both transistors run at the same current, both collector resistors too, so the voltage on them is the same, both Vce's are the same, so both Vbe's are the same. But if you want to run it with larger signals, with collector resistors this is no longer the case, as a large voltage swing in the collector resistors will manifest Early effect in both transistors, but in different directions, which means they no longer match. Solutions for this include using a current mirror or a cascode on top of the differential pair.
As frequency increases, capacitance matters more, and so does matching between the capacitance of both transistors.
Note:
A simple model of a BJT with Early effect:
\$ I_c = I_S e^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}} ( 1+\frac{V_{CE}}{V_A} )\$
If both transistors are matched, this means in identical conditions (temperature, Vce, Ic...) they have the same Vbe, current gain, Is, VT, VA, capacitance, etc. Common mode rejection in this circuit depends on how well the imperfections of both transistors match.

Given the schematic, the $V_{\text{BE}}$ of one bipolar must be the same as the $V{\text{BE}}$ of the other. The bases and emitters are wired together. And with the ideal emitter current sink (as shown), it's not possible for $V{_\text{BE}}$ variation over CM change (sans-saturation), even in non-ideal bipolar cases. The splitting of current doesn't change even if not equally split. A non-ideal sink changes that and with non-ideal bipolars the collector currents can, of course, be quite different and therefore divide up the ideal emitter current sink quite differently.

@periblepsis The Early effect will lead to VCM-induced Vbe changes. But as bobflux writes, they will be identical.

@tobalt The context is quite clear in the question -- ideal, identical bipolars and an ideal current sink. (And ideal resistors.)

@periblepsis Agreed. If the Early effect is considered a non-ideality (not far fetched, but also not explicitly stated), there will be no Vbe variation. I understand Bob's post in a way that allows for the Early effect to exist in ideal transistors.

I didn't see "ideal" in the question ... checks ... nope ;)
